# How to manipulate all six channels from Zoom H6 in Audio Midi Setup?

Tags: audio, microphone, skype, midi

Is there a way to manipulate all six channels on the multi-channel device in Audio Midi Setup?

If not, is there a way via the command line or another application to make sure that the applications use channels 3 & 4 rather than 1 & 2 from my [Zoom H6](https://www.zoom-na.com/products/field-video-recording/field-recording/h6-handy-recorder).

[image: Setup in Audio MIDI Setup]

[image: Output tab of setup]

### Background

I'm restarting a videocast that life caused me to put on hold last year (nothing majorly exciting to most people -- it's on medieval English literature and my research there).  I decided I wanted to have some extra flexibility and purchased a Zoom h6 to serve as a remote recorder and as an audio interface between by Blue Yeti Pro microphone and my Macbook Pro.

The Zoom H6 can be a stereo interface (so 2 channels in, 2 channels out via USB) or a multitrack interface (6 channels in, 2 channels out via USB).  With the stereo interface it can record at 48k/24 bit at a maximum, while with multitrack it can record at 96k/24 bit.  The six channels appear on the Mac as 1-6, and on the h6 as L,R,1,2,3,4 -- L and R are taken up by an interchangable capsule that can be an XY mic, extra XLR connectors, etc.

### Ideal

What I'd like to do is plug the Yeti Pro into the H6 on channels 1&2 on the H6 (so 3&4 on the Macbook Pro) and use it both as the mic for recording and as my primary microphone for Skype calls and the like to take advantage of some of the audio features of the h6.  The problem I'm running into is that the Mac is assuming that channels 1 and 2 (so L&R on the H6) are the default channels for recording and so doesn't pick up 3 and 4.

I'm thinking that the problem lies in configuring the H6 properly in Audio MIDI Setup, but it doesn't seem to give me the option of "forcing" the input to just channels 3 and 4, if you will.  Instead, the setup gives me this, with Mute and Thru greyed out for everything but the master.

Comment: What does the output tab from that screenshot look like?

Comment: Let me edit the post and add the output tab in as well.